# Double lines and centered stars in a table

Tags: tables, rules

I have a table, but I have a problem with formatting it:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm} c c c c} 

\\
Case & Entscheidungsbäume & Neuronale Netze & kNN & SVM \\ 
\hline\hline % inserts single horizontal line
\\
Accuracy in general & ** & *** & ** & **** \\ \hline 
Speed of learning with 
respect to number of 
attributes and the number of 
instances  & *** &* & **** & * \\ \hline
Speed of classification  &**** & **** & * & ****  \\ \hline
Tolerance to missing values  & *** & * & * & **  \\ \hline
Tolerance to irrelevant 
attributes  & *** & * & ** & ****  \\ \hline
Tolerance to noise  & ** & ** & *& ** \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Nonlinear Model Results} % title of Table
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
```

- I want to have a double thick line instead of a double normal line at the top and one thick line at the bottom.
- I want to have stars exactly in the middle of each cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution that uses `tabularx` and a macro `\stars` that takes as argument the number of stars and places them vertically centred. It requires the `multido` package;

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font = footnotesize, labelfont = sc}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{multido} 
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry} 
\newcommand*\stars[1]{\raisebox{-0.4\height}{\multido{\i = 1 + 1}{#1}{*}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering % used for centering table
\caption{Nonlinear Model Results} % title of Table
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X c c c c}
Case & Entscheidungsbäume & Neuronale Netze & kNN & SVM \\
\toprule\toprule % inserts double horizontal line
Accuracy in general & \stars {2}& \stars{3} & \stars {2}& \stars{4} \\
\midrule
Speed of learning with
respect to number of
attributes and the number of
instances & \stars{3} & \stars{1} & \stars{4} & \stars{1} \\
\midrule
Speed of classification & \stars{4} & \stars{4} & \stars{1} & \stars{4} \\
\midrule
Tolerance to missing values & \stars{1} & \stars{1} & \stars{1} & \stars {2} \\
\midrule
Tolerance to irrelevant
attributes & \stars{3} & \stars{1} & \stars {2}& \stars{4} \\
\midrule
Tolerance to noise & \stars {2}& \stars {2}& \stars {2}& \stars {2}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is really nice. How can I delete vertical lines at the both side of this table?

Comment: Oh! I forgot to mention they're there to visualise the margins (the table is exactly the width of lines). Remove the `showframe` option from the geometry package loading.

Comment: I would typeset the material in the first column raggedright rather than fully justified. That way, huge interword gaps can be avoided.

Comment: A separate suggestion: Instead of using `*` and the wrapper instruction `\raisebox{-0.4\height}{...}` in the definition of the `\stars` macro, you may want to use `\textasteriskcentered` and omit the `\raisebox` wrapper instruction entirely.

Comment: @Mico: I first thought it was an excellent suggestion… until I tested with other fonts than Computer Modern. With `heuristica` and `MinionPro` it requires adjusting by ~2-3pt. Thanks anyway: it indeed would have simplified the macro

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is what you are looking for.

```
% You should add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm} c c c c} 

\\
Case & Entscheidungsbäume & Neuronale Netze & kNN & SVM \\ 
\toprule \toprule % inserts double thick horizontal line on the top of table
\\
Accuracy in general & ** & *** & ** & **** \\ \hline 
Speed of learning with 
respect to number of 
attributes and the number of 
instances  & *** &* & **** & * \\ \hline
Speed of classification  &**** & **** & * & ****  \\ \hline
Tolerance to missing values  & *** & * & * & **  \\ \hline
Tolerance to irrelevant 
attributes  & *** & * & ** & ****  \\ \hline
Tolerance to noise  & ** & ** & *& ** \\ \bottomrule % inserts single thick horizontal line on the bottom of table
\end{tabular}
\caption{Nonlinear Model Results} % title of Table
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thnaks a lot, Is it possible to locate stars at the middle of cells? specially in the second row. It doesnt look good

Comment: There's no guarantee that the table will actually fit in the text block -- usually a major requirement.

Comment: @Kaja for this look at the pages 15 and 16 from this pdf file: http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mori/mori.pdf